# AlarmManager not firing when requested

Tags: android, alarmmanager

So I've made an app that's supposed to send a notification at 8:15 every Wednesday morning.  I'm using an AlarmManager to send inexact repeating alarms from a calendar date to open a pending intent that sends a notification.

What's currently happening is the notification is being sent only if you first download the app.  It did not go off this morning like it should have for myself or any of my users.  I'm wondering if the AlarmManager is being scheduled for one week after that first notification fires (i.e., a week after first downloading the app)?

Here is my manageNotifications method in MainActivity:

```
public void manageNotifications() {

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    /*
    sets alarm manager to go off at 8:15 in the morning every 7 days on Wednesday
     */
    alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
}//end manageNotifications
```

Here is my AlarmReceiver that the pending intent calls:

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder;
Intent notificationResultIntent;
ArrayList<Show> shows;
SharedPreferences spSpreadsheets, spNotifications;
final String showSpreadsheetURL = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ax2-gUY33i_pRHZIwR8AULy6-nbnAbM8Qm5-CGISevc/gviz/tq";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("AlarmReceiver created");
    spNotifications = context.getSharedPreferences("notificationToggle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    spSpreadsheets = context.getSharedPreferences("spreadsheets", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    if (spNotifications.getBoolean("notifications", false)) {
        int nextRegularShowIndex = 0, i = 0;

        shows = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            if (spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", "").equals(""))
                getShows(context);
            shows = processShowsJson(new JSONObject(spSpreadsheets.getString("showsSpreadsheet", "")));

            while (shows.get(i).getShowTime() != 0) {
            /*
            checks for first instance of a regular showtime
             */
                i++;
                nextRegularShowIndex = i;
            }
            checkForPastShows();
            notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)
                    .setContentTitle("Comedy Club of Jacksonville")
                    .setContentText(shows.get(nextRegularShowIndex).getComedian() + " headlines this weekend at the Comedy " +
                            "Club of Jacksonville.  Click to read more.")
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
            notificationResultIntent = new Intent(context, ThisWeekendFromNotification.class).putParcelableArrayListExtra("shows", shows);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(ThisWeekend.class);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationResultIntent);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
            System.out.println("Notification built");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end onReceive
    }
}
```

And here is my BootReceiver class used to reset the alarm when a phone is restarted:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
        java.util.Calendar calendar = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, java.util.Calendar.WEDNESDAY);
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        calendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 15);

    /*
    sets alarm manager to go off at 8:15 in the morning every 7 days on Wednesday
     */
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Try `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP` when using `setInexactRepeating(...)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you are using `setInexactRepeating()`. Unless your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, you cannot use `setInexactRepeating()` with an arbitrary period.

Second, `setInexactRepeating()` is inexact. Your alarm will not go off at 8:15am on a Wednesday. It will go off sometime. Quoting [the JavaDocs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29):

> Your alarm's first trigger will not be before the requested time, but it might not occur for almost a full interval after that time.

Third, as Squonk notes in the comment, you are using `RTC` as the alarm type. Your alarm will be further delayed, until the device wakes up for some other reason.

If your `targetSdkVersion` is below 19, you can use `setRepeating()` for an exact repeating alarm. Otherwise, use `set()` (pre-API Level 19) and `setExact()` (API Level 19+) to schedule your alarm, and schedule the next alarm as part of the work done when the alarm goes off. Also, use `RTC_WAKEUP`, if you want to wake the device out of sleep mode to do your work.

Comment: I have minSdkVersion set to 19.  I wasn't aware that inexact repeating might not fire until almost a full interval... I'll definitely change that.  With the emulator testing, it seemed consistent in that it would fire within a few minutes of its scheduled time.  Finally maybe it would be better to use RTC_WAKEUP with setRepeating.  Thank you both.